# How to get the total amount of log in a week from elk/kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I have a kibana interface, how do  I get the total amount of log data per week ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer I found is : http://ServerIP:9200/_cluster/stats?human&pretty' that has total data since first started.

Answer (score 1):

If you have marvel, you can ask it.

If you have daily indexes, you could get the stats for the last weeks worth of indexes and add them up.